# Swift: Facebook SDK, checking missing permissions after successful login

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift

I am trying to check for missing permissions once a user has successfully logged into the app.

```
func checkUserPermission()
    {
        let loginResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult()
        var missingPermissions: [String] = []
        if !loginResult.grantedPermissions.containsObject("public_profile")
        {
            missingPermissions.append("public_profile")
        }
        if !loginResult.grantedPermissions.containsObject("email")
        {
            missingPermissions.append("email")
        }
        if !loginResult.grantedPermissions.containsObject("user_friends")
        {
            missingPermissions.append("user_friends")
        }
        if !loginResult.grantedPermissions.containsObject("user_likes")
        {
            missingPermissions.append("user_likes")
        }

        println(missingPermissions)

    }
```

This function is ran when the app state changes to make sure I have all the permissions I need to make the app functional.

I am currently receiving this error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" but I cant seem to understand why. If the "FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()" is set then in theory the permissions should be set as well.

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue, I assumed `let loginResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult()` will store the permissions granted but to get the active permissions of the current logged in user you will have to rely on `FBSDKAccessToken`. So replacing `loginResult` with

`let loginResult: FBSDKAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()`

Should fix the issue. Also `grantedPermissions` will be changed to `permissions`. Here is the working function:

```
func checkUserPermission()
    {

        let loginResult: FBSDKAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()


        var missingPermissions: [String] = []
        if !loginResult.permissions.containsObject("public_profile")
        {
            missingPermissions.append("public_profile")
        }
        if !loginResult.permissions.containsObject("email")
        {
            missingPermissions.append("email")
        }
        if !loginResult.permissions.containsObject("user_friends")
        {
            missingPermissions.append("user_friends")
        }
        if !loginResult.permissions.containsObject("user_likes")
        {
            missingPermissions.append("user_likes")
        }

        println(missingPermissions)

        //let login: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
        //login.logInWithReadPermissions([""], handler: <#FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler!##(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, NSError!) -> Void#>)
        //login.loginw
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the (current) version 0.2.0 of Facebook SDK for Swift, this works:

```
func loginButtonClicked() {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn([ .publicProfile, .email ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in!")
            // Check for access to email address
            if declinedPermissions.contains(FacebookCore.Permission.init(name: "email")) {
                print("Email access declined")
            }
        }
    }
}
```